# selenium webdriver java dropdown box

Tags: java, selenium, drop-down-menu

need some help on this. Trying to learn Java and selenium at the same time isn't good but has to be done :(

I am trying to test a drop down spots box which contains:

```
<select name="sport" id="sport">
 <option value="1">Soccer</option>
 <option value="2">Basketball</option>
 </select>
```

I want to perform the follow: 
1: Assert box is present and its text is Soccer and Basketball 
2: Click Basketball and then click Soccer again. 
3: Assert the changes in the table below this box. (Have this done I think but need the above)

Code so far:

```
    Select sportDropdown = new Select(webBrowser.findElement(By.id("sport")));
    sportDropdown.selectByVisibleText("Soccer");
    assertEquals(sportDropdown, "Soccer");
```

Error received:

java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select@278806c4
Actual   :Soccer

I have no idea where this "Expected " value is coming from so any pointers would be great folks.

Note this is all in Java so please refrain from submitting code help in C#. Makes my life harder :(

Thanks
J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to get the text of the selected option for your assert statement to work. Currently you are asking whether a `WebElement` object is equal to a `String`.

```
Select sportDropdown = new Select(webBrowser.findElement(By.id("sport")));
sportDropdown.selectByVisibleText("Soccer");
assertEquals(sportDropdown.getFirstSelectedOption().getText(), "Soccer");
```

Comment: You sir are a star !!!! Thanks very much for the quick response and your code worked perfect first run after a slight tweak:                       assertEquals(sportDropdown.getFirstSelectedOption().getText(), "Soccer");

Comment: Ah Sorry, I took a guess at the Java binding for `.getFirstSelectedOption()`, in Python we use `.firstSelectedOption`so close enough.
Glad I could help, I'll edit the answer for future viewers.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone whose value equals the text value use the get attribute. It worked for me. May be work for someone else.

Select sportDropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("id")));
    sportDropdown.selectByValue("Value");
    Thread.sleep(3000);//This was needed since the page is refreshed whenever the value is selected.
    System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("id")).getAttribute("value"));